# Can't Install QtMobility [Windows 64-bit]

Tags: qt, installation, nokia, qt-mobility

I've downloaded and installed the QT SDK and downloaded the QT Mobility source.

Following the provided instructions, I navigated to my QtMobility directory via the Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)... note, this is the QtMobility dir with the bin, plugins, examples, etc. folders.

```
D:\
cd D:\Files\Downloads\QtMobility
configure
```

Regardless of whether I gave configure a -prefix parameter or not, the following output was displayed:

```
Checking available Qt
4.8.2
Checking make
... Unknown target environment .
Cannot find 'nmake', 'mingw32-make' or 'make' in your PATH
Aborting.
```

Of course, I then went to see if my computer had nmake in its PATH: the directory is added as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin
```

I went to CMD and typed in "nmake /?" to receive proper output.

What am I doing wrong? When I try to simply run nmake in the QTMobility directory, it displays:

```
NMAKE : fatal error U1064: MAKEFILE not found and no target specified
Stop.
```

Help, please! Thank you. :) I will continue attempting debugs on my own...

Comment: I'd be more worried by the `Unknown target environment` statement.

Comment: I'm still disconcerted, regardless.. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is late but you could simply run the visual studio command prompt, as it has specific env. variables preset to find nmake, etc.